# Given an equation, determine what conic section the equation represents

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I have the general equation $$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$ and I want to determine what conic section it represents according to the value of its coefficients or relations between them, is there a theorem where that is explained?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia article about conic sections ? It classifies the possibilies depending on the discriminant $B^2-4AC$ and also considers the degenerate cases.

Comment: Start with reading [Conic Section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section)

Answer (score 0):

This equation can be written in matrix notation, in terms of a symmetric matrix to simplify some subsequent formulae, as
\begin{equation}Q=(x,y)\begin{pmatrix}A & B/2\\
B/2&C\end{pmatrix}(x,y)^{T}+(D\quad E)(x,y)^{T}+F=0.
\end{equation}
the first matrix X is called the matrix of the quadratic form.
Q is a hyperbola if and only if det A<0,
Q is a parabola if and only if det A=0, and
Q is an ellipse if and only if det A>0.

Comment: I would not play it so loosely with those "if and only if" statements. Consider counterexamples $x^2 - 1 = 0$ or $x^2 + 1 = 0$. The graph of the first equation is a degenerate of two parallel lines. The second equation has no solution on the $x-y$ plane. Your rules would conclude that both were parabolas.